# Timeout getting seat map from SABRE

Tags: sabre

I'm working with SABRE API and I'm getting the following response 
`'Timeout exception occurred - PRS'` 
 while trying to use the method EnhancedSeatMapRQ to get one flight SeatMap. Has anyone faced a similar issue.

Comment: How long did you wait? Would it be acceptable to raise the timeout period? Of course, if the result doesn't return in *10* seconds it's better to retry than have the customer wait.

Comment: Another possibility is that you may be using a very old session. Sabre sessions are essentially terminal connections to mainframes - the same session always uses the same terminal. The load balancing code isn't very smart so old connections get slower as more and more sessions use them. Which is why Sabre recommends recycling sessions so that you can user fresher connections with a lighter load

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the service is not activated for your EPR.